# Ionic 2 Button will not right align button

Tags: angular, ionic2, ionic3

I'm looking for a way to pull my buttons to the right side of the page using Ionic2.  I have a form component with edit and save button's that I would like to pull to the right:

```
<div>
  <button ion-button (click)="toggleEdit()">
    <ion-icon name="create"></ion-icon>
  </button>
</div>
<ion-list>
  <ion-card-content>
    <ng-content>
    </ng-content>
  </ion-card-content>
  <div class="row center">
    <div class="col text-right">
      <button ion-button color="secondary" icon-end (click)="save()">
        <ion-icon name="save"></ion-icon>Save
      </button>
      <!--<a style="min-width: 50%;border-radius: 0px;" class="button button-dark icon-left ion-close">Cancel</a>
      <a style="min-width: 50%;border-radius: 0px;" class="button button-balanced icon-left ion-checkmark">Save</a>-->
    </div>
  </div>
</ion-list>
```

which generates a form that looks like this:[image]

As you can see the save button does not pull to the right,
I tried using text-right, but maybe that only works for ionic 1? Also tried to use the icon-end directive to pull it to the right but that doesn't seem to be working I guess it only works when there is another button.

Can anyone the proper Ionic way to align the save button to the right?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Please take a look at **[this working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/EOzzmtBFGIaC7FwL6eVk?p=preview)**. You could use an `ion-item` and add the `item-right` attribute to the button:

```
  <ion-card>
    <ion-item padding>
      <button default ion-button item-right>Button</button>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-card-header>
      Header
    </ion-card-header>
    <ion-card-content>
      The British use the term "header", but the American term "head-shot" the English simply refuse to adopt.
    </ion-card-content>
    <ion-item padding>
      <button default ion-button item-right>Button</button>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-card>
```

You can use the `padding` attribute (or `padding-left`, `padding-right`, `padding-bottom`, `padding-top`,...) to align it with the rest of the content.

That's one of the *most ionic ways* that I can think of...

Another option would be to just use css like this:

```
  <ion-card>
      ...
    <div style="width: 100%; padding: 26px; text-align:right;">
      <button ion-button>Button</button>
    </div>
  </ion-card>
```